# Instant Facebook 'Like' or link to Facebook page

Tags: social-media, facebook

I'm currently working on a youth brand project at work.
We need a Facebook link on the webpage to link to the Facebook page.

I believe that it should be a 'Like' button with a possible counter next to it which you can get from Facebook developers page. However the creative director figures it should be a 'Like' logo that when clicked takes the user to the Facebook page.

I am against this because:

• It won't provide the expected outcome for the user, once they are redirected to a whole new page they'll be like 'what the fu#€' and most probably lose interest and not even 'Like' the page

• It's not necessarily going to capture a 'Like' as the user may be overwhelmed with other things on the Facebook page and not hit 'Like'

To sum up, I believe the user will expect an automatic 'Like' once they hit the 'Like' button and MAYBE be confronted with an update widget incase they want to say more, that's it. They stay on the clients website.

Id like to see what the general mass figure about this one?

Answer (score 3):

**User perspective**: 
Facebook likes are used for expressing sympathy to a site/service/product, to bookmark it and eventually to see updates in their facebook newsfeed.
Since the user is on your site already, it's unlikely that he now wants to visit your facebook page. Plus, these like buttons are everywhere across the web and users are familiar with the way they work.

**'Webite' perspecitve**:
Uses facebook buttons with counters to get fans for their facebook page, to enable users to bookmark, to be able to talk to their users that are on facebook and to show that a) you are on facebook and b) have a number of fans there already.

Having said this, **I would fully agree with you - there should be the standard like widget as provided by facebook**.

(From your description it seems that the purpose for this 'facebook' integration is not fully clarified. Maybe it would be good to sit down and clarify which also might help to find the right answer.)

Comment: +1 I will add that the creative developer's user journey requires an extra click to *actually like* the page: they have to hit the Facebook page, and then click Like. Don't make it harder for someone to like your page.

Comment: Additionally the like button will adapt based on the logged in user. E.g it can switch language based on preference

Comment: agree with the purpose being unclear - maybe the creative director is thinking of a 'visit us on Facebook' type of thing rather than just 'liking' the page